# Prove that the limit is equal to one.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

How to prove that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 }\frac{\sin\big(\tan(x)\big)- \tan\big(\sin(x)\big)}{\arcsin\big(\arctan(x)\big)-\arctan\big(\arcsin(x)\big) } = 1$$
First terms in Taylor expansion of the numerator and denominator is $-\frac{x^7}{30}$. So the direct proof is not beautiful and hard.

Comment: You really should use parantheses to remove any potential ambiguity.  I'm assuming, for example, that $\sin{\tan{(x)}} = \sin{(\tan{(x)})}$.  Is that right?

Comment: i can't read it not really

Comment: @user46944 you are right. But I thing to much parantheses is not beautiful)

Comment: @user2109257 It's much more important to be clear on what you mean than to write beautiful math.  The real skill is writing beautiful math while being crystal clear in your meaning.

Comment: @user46944 "being crystal clear in your meaning" isn't it the definition itself of "beautiful maths"? :)

Comment: @MartinR thanks a lot. Then I close the question.